# Set each data id and assign it to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I am running the following code as I am trying to get each `.fotorama` id first and then assign each of them as each `.nav` link href.

```
$(".fotorama").each(function(){
     id = $(".fotorama", this).data("id");
     $(".nav li a").attr("href",  '#'+  id);
});
```

This is giving me `#undefined` to each `.nav` link tho

How should I do to set same href as each `.fotorama` id?

html, just an example, ids and menu items are dynamically generated on the site*

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href=" "></a></li>
  <li><a href=" "></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="fotorama" id="p1"></div>
<div class="fotorama" id="p2"></div>
<div class="fotorama" id="p2"></div>
```

Comment: Supply your HTML markup. At the moment this will apply the same href to all links with the value of the last `.fotorama` data-id

Comment: Is that `id` the html attribute `id` or some binded data? Also do you have nested `.fotorama` class elements? Because `$(".fotorama", this)`  is a selector that returns `.fotorama` inside `.fotorama`

Comment: just added some html example

Comment: Do you want them to match in order? So the first link should be #p1, then second #p2 and third #p2? Also, you shouldn't use the same ID more than once in a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = 0;   

$(".fotorama").each(function(){
   id = $(this).attr("id");
   $(".nav li a:eq(" + n + ")").attr("href",  '#'+  id);
   n++;
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3WVs/2/

Comment: This will apply the same `href` to all links with the value of the last `.fotorama` id

Comment: exactly, I am getting the same href for all links

Comment: @rob.m - I have provided a JS fiddle and updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @rob.m - it is changing the href, if you see my JSFiddle and hover over the links it shows the correct id.

Comment: Thanks dude.. I used this script to make youtube thumbnail image from URL dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Updated to account for HTML:

```
var links = $(".nav li a");

$(".fotorama").each(function(index){         
     links.eq(index).attr("href",  '#'+  this.id);
});
```

Will loop over each `.fotorama` element and set the corresponding `.nav li a` element (based on index) to use that ID.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LgXcn/1/)

Comment: I need to have unique href based on unique ids, they are not nested, please check updated question with the html

Comment: @rob.m It is in the example, if it isn't for you then something must be different. The HTML you originally posted had <a/> instead of </a> was that copied from your code as that would cause it to break?

Comment: no that was a typo here, let me tripple check, I must be having something conflicting

Comment: ok this is now working but the links are not in order, they get the next one id not the current

Answer (score 1):

That should work

```
var id, a, anchors = $(".nav li a");
$(".fotorama").each(function (i) {
  id = $(this).attr("id");
  a = $(anchors[i]);
  if (id && a && a.length)
    a.attr("href", '#' + id);
});
```